# Is it possible to run bitsontherun.com videos in shadowbox.js?

Tags: lightbox, jwplayer, shadowbox

I'm using bitsontherun.com to host and stream my videos.  It uses the latest version of JW player, but the player is handled by bitsontherun.  I also use shadowbox.js for my product image gallery.  I want to integrate my product videos into the gallery as well.  However, I can't figure out how to shadowbox videos from bitsontherun.  Normally I embed those videos into a page using a script tag like this:

```
<script src="http://content.bitsontherun.com/players/ThWcjaxZ-qLFOERCo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Shadowbox.js typically uses a link with a thumbnail image to launch the lightbox and associated player.  Anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is a basic implementation.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css">
        <style>
            .botrplayer {display: none}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Shadowbox.init({
                skipSetup: true
            });
            $(document).ready(function(){
                Shadowbox.setup($('.sbox'));//set up links with class of sbox
                $('a.sbox').live('click',function(event){
                    Shadowbox.open({
                        content:    $(this).siblings('.botrplayer').html(),
                        player:     'html',
                        title:      "Welcome",
                        height:     280,
                        width:      490
                    });
                    //Stops loading link
                    event.preventDefault();

                });
            });
        </script>
        <title>bitsontherun shadowbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The content of the document......</p>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="sbox">Open bitsonthe run video</a>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://content.bitsontherun.com/players/qgGMXVzB-Zdb9K7JT.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you wrap your links in a `div` with the `script` elements, you can reuse this code for all of them.

Hosted here: http://sandbox.jamesfishwick.com/bitsontherun/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the swf version of the video (see http://developer.longtailvideo.com/botr/system-api/urls/players.html) and link to that with a regular shadowbox (http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init();
</script>
<a href="http://content.bitsontherun.com/players/ThWcjaxZ-qLFOERCo.swf" rel="shadowbox">video</a>
```